# DataTables warning: table id=tableId- Cannot reinitialise DataTable

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

I have the following html code:

```
<table id="tableId" class="table table-striped display text-right" role="grid" style="width: 100%">
```

My javascript code is:

```
$(tableId).DataTable(data);
```

Filling the table works fine. But with updating the table, I get following error:

```
DataTables warning: table id=tableId- Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3
```

I tried to look for an answer. So far I found something about destroy() but nothing works. I guess it is a simple solution, but... How can I clear the whole table and fill it with new data.

I tried following:

```
$(tableId).dataTable({
      destroy: true });
```

But then the complete table doesn´t appear anymore.

Would be happy for some help.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
if($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable(tableId)){
   var table = $(tableId).DataTable();
   table.clear();
   table.rows.add(data).draw();
} else {
   $(tableId).DataTable(data);
}
```